# What are the ways for installing an extension in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2-enterprise

I need detailed information for installation of **`Magento 2 extension`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1: Magento 2 install extension using COMMAND LINE (Recommended)**

Your magento 2 extensions can be installed in a few minutes by going through these following steps

Step 1: Download/purchase the extension

Step 2: Unzip the file in a temporary directory

Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory

Step 4: Disable the cache under System­ >> Cache Management

Step 5: Enter the following at the command line:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

**Option 2 : add an extension's package to the root composer.json**

then run composer update

then run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**Option 3 :** You can also install extension from admin panel component manager as well , for more details please refer this link - https://magefan.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-extension-2/

Comment: Thanks...Also need to run php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: @AhmadVaqasKhan not needed each and every time , if you get any error related to factory method then you need to run it for the same

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways by which you can install the extension in the **Magento 2**.

They are as follows:

- Install the extension from the https://marketplace.magento.com directly from the admin side of your Magento
- Manual Installation of the Extension **(I recommend this one for better understanding & ease)**.
- Installation of the extension using Composer

**The Detailed description of the installation of the extensions are available below**

**1. Install the extension from the https://marketplace.magento.com
    directly from the admin side of your Magento**

- Go to the Admin panel of your Magento & follow thee below direction

  `System>Web Setup Wizard>Component Manager>`
- Sing in from your Magento Marketplace Account by clicking on the Sing
  in to Sync link it will ask for the Public & private Key of your
  Magento Account Just Copy & paste it at this place
- It will fetch all your purchased extensions in to your admin panel
  select the extension you wanted to install into your Magento & click
  on the install button & then just follow as it comes in front of you
  to do
  for More details follow this link http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/quick-tour/install-extension.html

**2. Manual Installation of the Extension**

Once the magento extension gets downloaded in below format

> < namespace_modulename-version.zip>

then follow these installation steps-

Unzip the Downloaded folder
Check for the unzipped folder whether it contains app folder or module name

- For app folder, overwrite the unzipped folder to the app folder of **Magento2** installation.
- If you are getting the folder with the module name, just copy paste it into the app code directory of your **Magento2** installation.
  Navigate to the Magento root directory path where the module is to be installed, via terminal (cmd) and run the following commands sequentially:

  ```
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

  php bin/magento cache:clean
  ```

**3. Installation of the extension using Composer**

Just copy the composer name/path of the of the module that you want to install & enter the below command through you command line using from your Magento root directory.

```
composer require module_composer_name/module_composer_path

composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your extension to **app/code** folder

Now your extension path like this : **app/code/Vendor/ModuleNameSpace**

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** ways to install the module in Magento 2

1. Using composer

   - with **component manager** [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/module-man/compman-start.html).
   - with **composer installation** [Alan kent explanation](https://alankent.me/2014/08/03/creating-a-magento-2-composer-module/)
2. Using file transfer

   - you need to move app folder in Magento2 root directory
   - run the following commands: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
   - clear the Cache

More informations [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-extensions-in-magento2).