# EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown extension extraxt file path not clear

Tags: magento2.2.6

> https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

I need to know, where should I extract the files of this plugin.(paths need app/code/ .... / ...)
Also need proper steps for installation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE you can follow [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189591/what-are-the-ways-for-installing-an-extension-in-magento-2/189598#189598)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below Steps

1. In `app/code` create folder named `Eadesigndev`
2. Create `RomCity` folder with in that
3. Copy all content in this and follow below steps
4. run `php bin/magento se:up` command in CLI
5. run `php bin/magento s:d:c` command in CLI
6. run `php bin/magento s:s:d -f` command in CLI

Comment: Thank you!  but I think my extension files are not working properly.

Comment: @BathiyaD install the core package also "https://github.com/EaDesgin/eacore"

Answer (score 0):

Follow this on how to install that module on your Magento Webshop

> 1. Copy its files to **your_Magento_root/app/code/Eadesigndev/RomCity**
> 2. After copying, run the upgrade command
>      **`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`**
>      then redeploy static content
>      **`php bin/magento setup:static-contents:deploy -f`**

Comment: Thank you! 
I have followed this steps, but still there is an issue. hope my extension files having some issues.

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Specified invalid parent id (Eadesigndev_Eacore::eadesign) this is a issue. i have changed some codes. but its not working. 

need help!

Comment: open menu.xml in path /etc/adminhtml/menu.xml and remove this `parent="Eadesigndev_Eacore::eadesign"`